# CVS error removing file from repository: Revision x.x is already locked by root

Tags: version-control, cvs

When I try to commit file `lib/foo/bar.jar` I get back

```
Removing lib/foo/bar.jar;
cvs [commit aborted]: Revision 1.6 is already locked by root
```

When I browse the repository, I see that all of the files in `lib/foo` end in *.v except for `bar.jar`.  There is a `bar.jar` ***and*** a `bar.jar.v`.

**Any ideas about how I can fix this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our CVS admin re-committed the file as root.  This unlocked it and allowed me to remove it.